# Getting tables from database stops working after running 3 times

Tags: database, vb.net

So this is a very weird problem I'm running into and I have no idea what might be causing it. Here's the code: http://hastebin.com/pemixowupa.vbs

The problem:

There are about 10 different tables in the database, which I'm collecting as the application loads so that I don't have to wait for a database connection whenever the information from the table is needed.

After collecting 3 tables (Exactly 3 tables or going through the while loop 3 times) it stops at:

> adp.Fill(TEMP_DataTable)

It doesn't error, it just shows my splash screen (which has a simple progress bar on it)

If any more information is needed, please ask. I'll post it in here

Thanks in advance!
Syths

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 tables in DB, then you must use DataSet, that contains DataTables
so use this :

```
 Public Shared Function RetrieveTableNames(ByVal table As String) As DataTable
    'Dim TEMP_DataTable As New DataTable
    Dim TEMP_DataSet as new DatSet

    If isConnected Then
        Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM " & table
        'MsgBox(sqlStr)
        Dim adp As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn)

        adp.Fill(TEMP_DataSet)

        adp.Dispose()
    End If

    Return TEMP_DataSet

    TEMP_DataSet.Dispose()
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, however doing this gives the following error: "DataTable is already linked to another DataSet".

Comment: Ok find that Data set and use it !  and read this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301216

Comment: And of course Begin with this ! :) have fun !: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p5.html